# How to prevent the screen from turning off when I open the lid?

Tags: macbook-pro

It happens only when the computer is plugged on a power source. The situation on battery is not the same, knowing the computer goes to sleep.

When I close the lid, the computer behaves correctly:

- Screen turns off
- Does not go to sleep (front light stays on and does not flash)
- Still can hear fans

But when I open the lid:

- The screen turns on...
- ...and turn off about 2 seconds after

I can see my desktop background, and the login window for 2s, and after that the screen becomes black (actually it turns off, it's not backlighted black).

The little trick I found is to reduce the luminosity thanks to the F1 key, and then increase it again to come back to maximum luminosity.

> Computer specs :
>   - Macbook Pro 15" bought 2 months ago
>   - It came with OS X Lion already installed
>   - I choose the screen resolution option (don't know if it matters)

It's not really handicapping since I found this little trick, but it's a little bit annoying to have to do that every time I open my Macbook.

**UPDATE : Check out my related question here : [How to prevent the screen from turning off when I open the lid?](https://superuser.com/questions/335805/how-to-prevent-the-screen-from-turning-off-when-i-open-the-lid/) It seems that the problem has been solved by Mountain Lion.**

Comment: I'd be taking it back to have it fixed under warranty. 2 months old you shouldn't be having problems like this.

Comment: Warranty ? Don't you think there is a way to solve it by by own ? Even by reinstalling OS X Lion or something ?

Comment: Possibly. But if its when you open the lid it sounds like a hardware driven event. I would back up your windows install, re-install Lion and see what happens then. If the problem persists then get down to the genius bar or whatever they call it.

Comment: This question has a cross-post over at Ask Different: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25153/screen-turns-off-at-lid-opening

Answer (score 1):

I used to have this, until I installed Mountain Lion. Now it doesn't do it anymore, but if I close the lid and then open it after 10 seconds or so, then I have to wait several minutes to get past the black screen. (It's fine if the lid's been closed for more than 10 or 15 minutes.) I don't know which problem is worse...

Comment: Thanks for the info. Actually, my problem was related to the Mac OS integrated Internet Sharing option. Check my question here : http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25153/screen-turns-off-at-lid-opening. I took the opportunity to try it again with Mountain Lion, and it doesn't seem to be a problem any more in this version of Mac OS. I updated both of my question.